# Azure AD Powershell: Extract the User's last Logon Time

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to extract the user's last logon time on our Active Directory, and I found this script, which should do the trick:

```
Install-Module AzureADPreview
Import-Module AzureADPreview
$Cred = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Cred

$Users = Get-MsolUser -all
$Headers = "DisplayName`tUserPrincipalName`tLicense`tLastLogon" >>C:\list.csv
ForEach ($User in $Users)
    {
    $UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName
    $LoginTime = Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -top 1 -filter "userprincipalname eq '$UPN'" | select CreatedDateTime
    $NewLine = $User.DisplayName + "`t" + $User.UserPrincipalName + "`t" + $User.Licenses.AccountSkuId + "`t" + $LoginTime.CreatedDateTime
    $NewLine >>'C:\list.csv'
    }
```

But for some reason Powershell can't seem to recognize the "Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs" input, even though according to technet the correct Module for it is "AzureADPreview" which I install at the beginning of the script:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadauditsigninlogs?view=azureadps-2.0-preview

Do you know If i need any other modules to run this script? Are there maybe any other ways to get to this info? I'd need a CSV-File with all users and their last LogonTime.

Thank you for your help.

Cheers,

Gabe

Edit: Here's the Error-Message:

```html
Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs : The term 'Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:12 char:18
+     $LoginTime = Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -top 1 -filter "userprinc ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct requirements for the [AzureADPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) module?. Can you edit your question and post the complete exxor message you are receiving?

Comment: To be honest: no. But I can't seem to find which requirements I need... the Technet-Article says that it Only needs AzureADPreview, which I installed. I posted the error-message above.

Comment: please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0-preview

Comment: Okay, yes I already installed both modules, I now also de- and re-installed them, but it still doesn't recognizes the Module...

Comment: Are you sure you have both modules installed correctly? Does `Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureAD*` give you the expected results?

Comment: Yes ... I just entered it in at it shows me AzureAD and AzureAD Preview

Comment: Okay... i've been able to do it...you just have to use "AzureADPreview\Connect-AzureAD" to log into Azure...thank you for your help guys.

Comment: @Gabe Thanks for sharing what worked for you. Please post it as an answer so it benefits others in the community.

Comment: Your machine can get into a situation where not all AzureADPreview cmdlets are installed as part of the module install. A historic screw up by MS if you installed AzureAD module first. You have to uninstall and manually delete module files for AzureAD and AzureADPreview. When done, first install AzureADPreview, then AzureAD.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me
`Install-Module AzureADPreview -AllowClobber -Force`