# How to check when existing Azure AD users from Azure portal has been disabled or blocked and lastsignin time using PowerShell or KQL?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-cloud-services, kql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0
[Azure Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYs2O.png)

How to check when existing Azure AD users from Azure portal has been disabled or blocked and lastsignin time using PowerShell or KQL?

Answer (score 1):

Please check powershell commands.
To check the users who are

**Enabled:**

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true' | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department,LastDirSyncTime
```

**Disabled:**

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | where {$_.accountenabled -eq $false}
```

(or)

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq false' | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department,LastDirSyncTime
```

**To get the last logon time of one user with upn**

> Note: this requires to install azure ad preview module like:
>
> ```
> Install-Module AzureADPreview
> Import-Module AzureADPreview
> Connect-AzureAD
> ```

```
 Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -Top 1 -all $true | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -like "user@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"}| select UserPrincipalName,CreatedDateTime
```

**Please try this in powershell for more than one user:**

```
   Install-Module AzureADPreview
    Import-Module AzureADPreview
    $Cred = Get-Credential
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
    Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Cred
    
    #$Users = Get-MsolUser -all
    $disabledUsers=Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq false'
    
    $Headers = "UserPrincipalName`tLastLogon" >>C:\list.csv
   
 ForEach ($User in $disabledUsers)
    {
    $UPN =( $User).UserPrincipalName
    $LastLoginTime = Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -top 1 -filter "userprincipalname eq '$UPN'" | select CreatedDateTime
    $NewLine =  $User.UserPrincipalName + "`t" +  $LoginTime.CreatedDateTime
    $NewLine >>'C:\list.csv'
    }
```

> Note: If errors occur ,please check if azureadpreview module  is
> installed properly > see [this](https://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2019/08/azure-ad-logs-powershell-azureadpreview.html)

**References:**

1. [PowerShell: Getting all Azure AD User IDs Last Login date and Time
   – Higginson Consultancy ltd](https://www.higginson.org/powershell-getting-all-azure-ad-user-ids-last-login-date-and-time/)
2. [Extract the User's last Logon Time-so reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062419/azure-ad-powershell-extract-the-users-last-logon-time)
3. [check-if-office-365-user-is-blocked](https://morgantechspace.com/2018/02/check-if-office-365-user-is-blocked-or-not-powershell.html)